# Batch Script to execute a file with a variable Name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have to run a file with a variable name

> "From_date_todaydate.bat"

so I wrote a batch file :

> CALL C:\Generated\From_*_To_todaydate.bat

soI got this error

> the system cannot fint the path specified

I think that The problem is that this code doesn't expand the wildcard character (*),
how can I proceed ?

Comment: is it the only bat file under c:\generated ?

Comment: No there is many batch files under the mentioned path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try something like :

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b c:\generated\from_*_to_todaydate.bat') do call c:\generated\%%i
```

Comment: please provide some of the filenames

Comment: it's ok , it was my fault  : thaaaank you)